# Build a maven project with Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to get an existing Jenkins job working in Gitlab CI.

On Jenkins my project gets build via `mvn clean package` and the resulting war file is then moved to a tomcat container. Once finished, another job gets triggered to call a specific URL of this project to do some stuff which is unrelated to my question. When this is done, tomcat stops and the 2 jobs are finished.

How can I do that with Gitlab CI?

I started doing sth like

```
image: cdornbusch/tomcat-maven

stages:
  - build

build:
  script:
    - "mvn clean tomcat:run"
    - "echo 'TEST'"
  stage: build
```

but I never see the echo 'TEST' which makes pretty sense since the task `mvn tomcat:run` never stops...but how can I build and deploy the project and then call a specific url of it??? Once the build is done, I don't need the tomcat instance anymore.

---

Just a side note, I use my own docker image which installs an Ubuntu with Maven, Java and Tomcat to fulfill my project requirements.

Comment: I would say the job build is doing lots of things. I would create four stages : build,deploy,test,cleanup. For each stage, i would create one job. This allows the jobs to be run one by one in a sequential way.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't resolve the issue I have with doing sth after I deployed the project.

Comment: Still no answer ? question interests me